# The selected row values are not getting selected from a table in firefox but working in chrome . Code is in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

This is my code. I have a table in HTML. When I click on a row, the values of that row get selected.
**console.log(sitepop);**  shows me the selected values. In chrome, I am getting the required values, but in Firefox, I am getting an empty array.

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr' ,function(){
        var trChild = $(this).children();
        var selected = $(this).hasClass("selected");
        $("#table tr").removeClass("selected");
        if(!selected)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        var sitepop = [trChild[1].outerText,trChild[2].outerText];
        console.log(sitepop);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/site_data',
            data:{ 'sitepop': sitepop
                    },
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(demo){
                console.log("successful")
            }

    });
});
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with your code "working" ?

Comment: Would you please provide the Html code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i got the solution . It was because of the outerText parameter that I was taking . Chrome has outerText but firefox doesnot. So I chose innerText instead . This works for both the browsers .